# Why is this div height not calculated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anybody know why the Height of the yellow-box is not calculated correctly (100px)?

I need to know define the css so the JavaScript-Part knows the real height...

```
<div id="footer">
 <div class="header">
  Header
 </div>
 <div class="content">
  Content blub    
 </div>
</div>​
```

Here is a jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3nM7f/

Comment: Because its height is 100% of 148px.

Comment: How can i archive 100% of 148px - height of header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're defining it using percentages `%` instead of pixels `px`.

You need to change

```
.content{
    height:100%;   
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

to

```
.content{
    height:100px;   
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

and all your sections will appear correctly.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3nM7f/3/) here.

Comment: Yeah but footer-height is variable by the user... so i dont know the fixed height of .content :o/

Comment: In that case you can set .content to 50% height, so that it adapts to whatever is placed in the footer and all sections can be viewed.

Comment: No, because .content should be ALL the available height (minus the header) of #footer

Comment: OK, in this case, you need to use height and max-height on the same element, but one using % and the other using pixels. e.g. height = 148px, max-height = 100%

Comment: i dont get what you mean.. can u fork my jsfiddle please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3nM7f/7/ something like this (maybe the other way round). I don't really understand what you want, maybe edit your jsfidde to show what input is going into the footer

Comment: But the alert is still 148px not 123px (calculated) :o/

Answer (score 1):

Height 100% always takes the height of the parent div. You can use javascript to set its height if you want. You need to include jquery js file in your website header. syntax maynot be 100% correct but you can use the concept

```
var height = $(".footer").css("height") - $(".header").css("height");
$(".content").css("height",height);
```

Comment: I know this way. But i need a more generic one. Imagine there are more elements above the .content box who limits its available space

Comment: Ok here you go. This thing is as I said, height 100% will always take the height of the parent div, which in this case is footer. But as you keep adding divs like header or some more like header1, header2 .. all these will push the div named "content" below and content will always take the space that is available. but if you try calculating the height of "content" it will give you "100%" that is 148px (parent's height). You can try adding more divs and see what happens